# Сравнение символов строки ведет себя странно C++

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте.

Вот пример.

```
std::string Main = "12word1";

for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    if (Main[i] == '1') {
        std::cout << Main[i];
    }
```

В этом случае в консоль попадет две единицы, потому, что в строке они 2 раза встречаются. Пишу так:

```
std::string Main = "12word1";

for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    if (Main[i] == '1' || '2') {
        std::cout << Main[i];
    }
```

Вроде бы, если элемент строки равен 1 или 2 тогда выводить его, но вместо `1 2 1` он выводит строку целиком. В чем ошибка?

Comment: Хм... Интересно, спасибо.

Comment: +вспоминаем что приоритет у "==" выше чем у "||" отсюда и решение из 1-го коментария

Comment: А я думал такие ошибки очевидны...

Предупреждений компилятор не выводил?

Comment: Нет, не было.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте написать так:

```
if ((Main[i] == '1') || (Main[i] == '2')) {
        std::cout << Main[i];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка в том что выражение '2' всегда истинно.

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    if ((Main[i] == '1') || (Main[i] == '2')) {
        std::cout << Main[i];
    }
```